# Shopify API in node.js/React. How to read and write API in Shopify App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, shopify

I'm a total newbie in coding and shopify and I knew how to fetch API in vanilla JS but I'm not exactly sure how it works in node.js and React. I've been trying my best to read the documentation but everything still seems so vague. And the tutorials online seem different or outdated. I did manage to get through using Shopify CLI. Basically, I want to read the product names and update them through the app.

So far all I want to do first is console.log the product names but I can't seem to do it. I am able to access https://[name].myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json that returns the api but I can't put it on my frontend. So far I get an GET https://7172-60-***-***-**.jp.ngrok.io/undefined/admin/api/2022-10/products.json 404 with the codes that I have. What I was trying to do with my code is that the API will be console logged when the form button is clicked.

Here are my codes.

Backend code web/index.js

```
import { join } from "path";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import express from "express";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { Shopify, LATEST_API_VERSION } from "@shopify/shopify-api";

import applyAuthMiddleware from "./middleware/auth.js";
import verifyRequest from "./middleware/verify-request.js";
import { setupGDPRWebHooks } from "./gdpr.js";
import productCreator from "./helpers/product-creator.js";
import redirectToAuth from "./helpers/redirect-to-auth.js";
import { BillingInterval } from "./helpers/ensure-billing.js";
import { AppInstallations } from "./app_installations.js";
import {Product} from '@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/2022-10/index.js';
import cors from 'cors';


const USE_ONLINE_TOKENS = false;

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.BACKEND_PORT || process.env.PORT, 10);

// TODO: There should be provided by env vars
const DEV_INDEX_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/frontend/`;
const PROD_INDEX_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/frontend/dist/`;

const DB_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/database.sqlite`;

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, ""),
  HOST_SCHEME: process.env.HOST.split("://")[0],
  API_VERSION: LATEST_API_VERSION,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  // See note below regarding using CustomSessionStorage with this template.
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.SQLiteSessionStorage(DB_PATH),
  ...(process.env.SHOP_CUSTOM_DOMAIN && {CUSTOM_SHOP_DOMAINS: [process.env.SHOP_CUSTOM_DOMAIN]}),
});

// NOTE: If you choose to implement your own storage strategy using
// Shopify.Session.CustomSessionStorage, you MUST implement the optional
// findSessionsByShopCallback and deleteSessionsCallback methods.  These are
// required for the app_installations.js component in this template to
// work properly.

Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.addHandler("APP_UNINSTALLED", {
  path: "/api/webhooks",
  webhookHandler: async (_topic, shop, _body) => {
    await AppInstallations.delete(shop);
  },
});

// The transactions with Shopify will always be marked as test transactions, unless NODE_ENV is production.
// See the ensureBilling helper to learn more about billing in this template.
const BILLING_SETTINGS = {
  required: false,
  // This is an example configuration that would do a one-time charge for $5 (only USD is currently supported)
  // chargeName: "My Shopify One-Time Charge",
  // amount: 5.0,
  // currencyCode: "USD",
  // interval: BillingInterval.OneTime,
};

// This sets up the mandatory GDPR webhooks. You’ll need to fill in the endpoint
// in the “GDPR mandatory webhooks” section in the “App setup” tab, and customize
// the code when you store customer data.
//
// More details can be found on shopify.dev:
// https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/mandatory-webhooks
setupGDPRWebHooks("/api/webhooks");

// export for test use only
export async function createServer(
  root = process.cwd(),
  isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  billingSettings = BILLING_SETTINGS
) {
  const app = express();

  app.set("use-online-tokens", USE_ONLINE_TOKENS);
  app.use(cookieParser(Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY));

  applyAuthMiddleware(app, {
    billing: billingSettings,
  });

  // Do not call app.use(express.json()) before processing webhooks with
  // Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process().
  // See https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-node/blob/main/docs/usage/webhooks.md#note-regarding-use-of-body-parsers
  // for more details.
  app.post("/api/webhooks", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(req, res);
      console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${e.message}`);
      if (!res.headersSent) {
        res.status(500).send(e.message);
      }
    }
  });

  // All endpoints after this point will require an active session
  app.use(
    "/api/*",
    verifyRequest(app, {
      billing: billingSettings,
    })
  );

  app.get('/admin/api/2022-10/products.json', async (request, response) => {
    const test_session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(request, response);
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    await Product.all({
      session: test_session,
    });
});

  app.get("/api/products/count", async (req, res) => {
    const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(
      req,
      res,
      app.get("use-online-tokens")
    );
    const { Product } = await import(
      `@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/${Shopify.Context.API_VERSION}/index.js`
    );

    const countData = await Product.count({ session });
    res.status(200).send(countData);
  });

  app.get("/api/products/create", async (req, res) => {
    const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(
      req,
      res,
      app.get("use-online-tokens")
    );
    let status = 200;
    let error = null;

    try {
      await productCreator(session);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Failed to process products/create: ${e.message}`);
      status = 500;
      error = e.message;
    }
    res.status(status).send({ success: status === 200, error });
  });

  // All endpoints after this point will have access to a request.body
  // attribute, as a result of the express.json() middleware
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const shop = Shopify.Utils.sanitizeShop(req.query.shop);
    if (Shopify.Context.IS_EMBEDDED_APP && shop) {
      res.setHeader(
        "Content-Security-Policy",
        `frame-ancestors https://${encodeURIComponent(
          shop
        )} https://admin.shopify.com;`
      );
    } else {
      res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", `frame-ancestors 'none';`);
    }
    next();
  });

  if (isProd) {
    const compression = await import("compression").then(
      ({ default: fn }) => fn
    );
    const serveStatic = await import("serve-static").then(
      ({ default: fn }) => fn
    );
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(serveStatic(PROD_INDEX_PATH, { index: false }));
  }

  app.use("/*", async (req, res, next) => {
    if (typeof req.query.shop !== "string") {
      res.status(500);
      return res.send("No shop provided");
    }

    const shop = Shopify.Utils.sanitizeShop(req.query.shop);
    const appInstalled = await AppInstallations.includes(shop);

    if (!appInstalled && !req.originalUrl.match(/^\/exitiframe/i)) {
      return redirectToAuth(req, res, app);
    }

    if (Shopify.Context.IS_EMBEDDED_APP && req.query.embedded !== "1") {
      const embeddedUrl = Shopify.Utils.getEmbeddedAppUrl(req);

      return res.redirect(embeddedUrl + req.path);
    }

    const htmlFile = join(
      isProd ? PROD_INDEX_PATH : DEV_INDEX_PATH,
      "index.html"
    );

    return res
      .status(200)
      .set("Content-Type", "text/html")
      .send(readFileSync(htmlFile));
  }
  );

  return { app };
}

createServer().then(({ app }) => app.listen(PORT));
```

This is my frontend /web/pages/index.js

```
import { React, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  Page,
  Layout,
  Card,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormLayout,
  TextField,
  Stack,
} from "@shopify/polaris";
import { ResourcePicker } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import axios from "axios";

const axiosGetData = () => {
  axios({
    url: `${process.env.SHOP}/admin/api/2022-10/products.json`,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'X-Shopify-Access-Token': `${process.env.TOKEN}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};


const index = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Name");
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = useCallback((newValue) => setValue(newValue), []);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    setState(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(value);
    axiosGetData();
  }

  function handleCancel() {
    setState(false);
  }

  function handleSelection(resources) {
    setState(false);
    resources.selection.map((name) => (name.handle = value));
    console.log(resources.selection);
  }

  return (
    <Page title="My Shop">
      <Layout>
        <Layout.Section>
          <Card title="Change Product Name" sectioned>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormLayout>
                <TextField
                  label="Type on the input the new name and select which product name to change"
                  value={value}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <Button primary submit>
                  Select Product
                </Button>
              </FormLayout>
              <ResourcePicker
                resourceType="Product"
                open={state}
                onCancel={handleCancel}
                onSelection={handleSelection}
              />
            </Form>
          </Card>
        </Layout.Section>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default index;
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue is that your GET URL on the FE is incorrect. Your server is running on localhost/ngrok, so to hit it you should take out the `${process.env.SHOP}` in your URL. So the route should just be -> `/admin/api/2022-10/products.json`.

You can see an example of this and get a better idea of how it works by going through the example app build that Shopify provides (https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/build-app-example).

It's important to note that these aren't Shopify specific concepts, so you should brush up on Express app routing a bit and how to hit your endpoints from your FE. Shopify abstracts a lot of things in their templates and it's easy to get confused where things are happening so taking time to read through the code and see what's going on will be super helpful going forward

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. By any chance is this you https://youtu.be/whD9EbKS5GE ? Because dude I just watched your tutorial and its the best out there. I was hoping for a second video.

Comment: I tried it and I still got a GET https://7172-**-***-***-50.jp.ngrok.io/admin/api/2022-10/products.json 404 problem. Axios says its a "Request failed with status code 404". :(((

Comment: Yes that is me! I will start making content again as soon as my current Shopify app is approved, hoping within a couple weeks